# Django Rest app not using media root correctly to serve images

Tags: python, django, image, django-rest-framework, image-uploading

I have a project that has 3 apps, one named stores with store models, products with product models, and api which is the rest framework app that serves the Json results to clients. I set the media root in settings.py as `MEDIA_ROOT = '/photos/'` and the upload works for both product and store models. The main problem here is that for some reason the rest framework returns a url that references the api app instead of the products or stores apps for the media root url. here are my models

```
class Product(models.Model):

def get_image_path(instance, filename):
    return '/Products/' + filename

picture = models.ImageField(width_field=None, max_length=100, blank =True, null =True)
```

store:

```
class Store(models.Model):


def __str__(self):
    return self.name


def get_image_path(instance, filename):
    return os.path.join('productphotos', 'stores', filename)

picture = models.ImageField(width_field=None, max_length=100, blank =True, null =True)
```

How do i set the mediaroot to the project directory instead so that all apps in the project reference it as mediaroot instead of themselves?

The upload works and upoads the pictures to the instructed directories in the root of the project (where manage.py is found), but the rest framework thinks it should get the media from the api app.. what's the proper way of doing this? here are screenshots:

the path uploaded to
[image: Successful upload path]

the path returned in json
[image: Path returned by DRF]

Comment: You didn't provide enough informations here. What's the expected url - one string, what's the one Django REST framework returns ? How come one of your upload_to is absolute ?

Comment: I've edited it to provide more information, the current way brought an error when uploading (I forgot to test after changing) So I just edited it back to its previous behaviour (gotten rid of the get_image_path method)

Comment: There are still some inconsistencies. The image path in the picture is different from the `MEDIA_ROOT` in the settings. Are you sure your `MEDIA_ROOT` settings is absolute ?

Comment: No i'm not, I actually don't know what i'm doing and ended up commenting out the media root, but now it isn't even uploading at all.. by absolute you mean I should give the `MEDIA_ROOT` an absolute path from my root drive, i.e `C:\users\ME\documents\pycode\shoplist\pictures` instead of the way I was going at it? forgive me if my questions are stupid I'm a total beginner. It must be frustrating for you :(

Comment: It's OK, we all started one day. It's better the MEDIA_ROOT path start from the root drive. The settings should have BASE_DIR which is the directory manage.py is located in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `MEDIA_URL` setting is the URL path in the browser. The `MEDIA_ROOT` setting is the root directory on your server, and should be an absolute path.

```
MEDIA_URL = '/pictures/'

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'uploaded_pictures')
```

Also, if you want `Product` and `Store` pictures to go into different sub directories, for example `pictures/products/` and `pictures/store/`, you'd need to set the `upload_to` argument on the model field. For example

```
picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/', ... )
```

**Edit:** To serve static and media files during development, add this at the end of the urls.py

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
    from django.conf.urls.static import static

    urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
    urlpatterns += static(
        settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Thanks, It works now.. the path stays the same, but the final question is how to serve this to a client cs it just says page not found when i click the link in the browser.. do i need  separate server or is the django dev server enough?

Comment: The dev server needs to be told to serve the directory, I added it to the answer.

Comment: I've added that, tried both before and after the `urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns)` line but it still returns  404 error

Comment: Never mind that, I added it to root url.conf and it worked magic.. thanks